# Automating Alchemy pad segments in Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro

How can one automate the movement of the performance pads in Logic Pro X's new Alchemy Synth?

Is there a way to record the movements and map that to automation for further tweaking?

I see the mappings there, but its not really logical in terms of defining a path.

Is it possible to add multiple layers of automation in Logic? E.g. One for the X direction, one for the Y.

Comment: just select 'touch' for your automation option in the channel strip and it records your real time manipulations of all that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Alchemy 'Perform' section has 2 pads,

1. Transform Pads

[image: Transform Pads]

2. XY Pads

[image: XY Pads]

---

Change the 'Automation Mode' from 'Read'(default) to 'Touch'

[image]

[image]

From 'Automation Parameter' dropdown, choose 'Alchemy > Perform > Transform Pad X'

[image: Alchemy > Perform > Transform Pad X]

Note that this will set 'Automation Parameter' to both Transform Pad X and Transform Pad Y

[image: both Transform Pad X and Transform Pad Y]

Now press 'R' and then click-hold the rectangular 'focus' on the Transform Pad and move it as you wish, the corresponding X-Y coordinates will be plotted as automation.

[image: X-Y coordinates will be plotted as automation]

P.S : LPX 10.3.2